# Dark mode defaults back to light mode on reload/navigating to new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

everyone.

I have a dark mode toggle that seems to be working great, just that it's clearing the mode it's on when navigating to new page or when refreshing.

How do I ensure this doesn't happen?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useDarkMode = () => {
  let [theme, setTheme]: any = useState("light");
  const colorTheme = theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark";

  useEffect(() => {
    const root = window.document.documentElement;

    root.classList.remove(colorTheme);
    root.style.colorScheme = theme;
    root.classList.add(theme);
  }, [theme, colorTheme]);

  return [colorTheme, setTheme] as const;
};

export default useDarkMode;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your mode in session storage or in local storage.
You check that your variable is well initialized at the beginning otherwise you put the light mode by default and you apply to the page. And when you change the mode you don't forget to modify the value in session storage or local storage.